# Cut,Copy and Paste in eclipse GEF Editors

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am creating eclipse gef editor using BPMN2 EMF models. Now i am almost end to editor functionality. But i am not clear to implement Cut,Copy and Paste functionality. i searched lot in net but all the tutorials i have seen using clone method in Models. In default bpmn2 models doesn't implement clone interface. Please suggest me any idea to achieve cut,copy and paste in gef editor without cloning.

```
                   Thanks.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the gef logic example:
they use a CopyTemplateAction (standard GEF action) and a custom LogicPasteTemplateAction.

These actions leverage the GEF command framework to istantiate a new Command to create the new model part.

Comment: Hi Cerealk, Thanks for your reply . In logic copy action is not working properly. i already checked in logic and graphiti editors.Can you give some more idea?

Comment: Copy Action: you put the selected element in the clipboard (Clipboard.getDefault().setContents(...)). The selectedElement is defined via selection service. PasteAction: you get the model from the clipboard, clone it and insert in the model currently edited. EcoreUtil.copy(EObject) is the "EMF-approved" way to clone an EMF object. (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/390465/ emf clone object). If you insert the copyed object via command you also have access to the undo/redo operation offered by the command stack.